# Android Library Update hanging eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When I open up eclipse android Library update hangs eclipse. It never progresses and seems stuck.
[image]

I can no longer clean or build my projects. I followed the [instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9766986/android-library-update-eclipse-task-randomly-stuck-my-eclipse-on-start) of deleting/moving .metadata folder but it doesn't help.

Comment: Have try to stop the progress and then cleaning your project?

Comment: yeah I have done that, but this problem comes every time I open up eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that some process is hanging on to a file handle that Eclipse needs (and only Eclipse, not the SDK manager which is weird.)

Assuming that you have actually cleared the Metadata AND deleted [user home]/.android/cache:

1. kill Eclipse
2. Run the SDK Manager get all the updates you need
3. on windows: restart your machine
4. on other platforms: make sure ANYprocess that has access to your metadata or your cache is killed
5. restart eclipse wait patiently for everything to catch up.

HTH